# curl: transfer closing when trying to install perlbrew

Tags: perl, curl, perlbrew

I'm trying to install perlbrew in my mac OSX and this error keeps popping in my terminal, not really sure what this means

> ### Download the latest perlbrew
>
> curl: (18) transfer closed with ###### bytes remaining to read

I understand vaguely that this error is related to poor network service, am I right?

Can anyone help me how to install perlbrew offline and how to install modules after perlbrew is done!

Your help is appreciated

Comment: not sure about perlbrew offline, I believe it needs internet to actually install perl versions. To address your second question: You can easily set up cpanm to install modules to the currently chosen perl. ( see http://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html ). It rarely failed me.

Comment: @bytepusher, `perlbrew` will reuse previously downloaded Perl tarballs, so you could install `perl` offline using `perlbrew` by putting the right tarball in the `dists` dir.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to install perlbrew in my mac OSX

There are lots of OSX versions.  Can you narrow it down a bit?

> I understand vaguely that this error is related to poor network
>   service, am I right?

If the command you issued was:

```
$ \curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

then that tells a program called `curl` to download the file `install.perlbrew.pl` from the internet, then execute the file with a program called `bash`.  You can view that file by entering the url specified in the command in your browser:

```
http://install.perlbrew.pl
```

As you can see, the file is very short.

The error means that for some reason `curl` couldn't download the entirety of a file it was trying to download.  That could be because the server(where the file resides) dropped your connection, or the internet connection on your side was disrupted.

> Can anyone help me how to install perlbrew offline

You *could* go to the url and copy the text and paste it into a local file called, say,  `install_perlbrew.pl`.  Then you *could* execute that file offline like this:

```
$ bash install_perlbrew.pl
```

That file is a program and when you execute the program with `bash`, the program uses `curl` yet again to retrieve another file, namely perlbrew, from the internet.  You could also copy the perlbrew file to your computer and modify the install script to use the local perlbrew file, but then when you execute the perlbrew file, it also uses `curl` to retrieve even more files from the internet, and so on and so on.

So unless you know bash scripting and you can modify the install script to use all local files, and you have the patience to track down all the files required and copy them to local files, you are not going to be able to *install* perlbrew offline.

> Can anyone help me how to ... install modules after perlbrew is done!

If the module name is File::Monitor, you would install it like this:

```
$ cpan File::Monitor
```

If it's your first time using the `cpan` command, you will see this:

```
$ cpan File::Monitor

CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.
If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each
configuration option instead.

Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes]
```

Hit return to use the default answer (which is specified in brackets).  After cpan automatically configures itself, it will install the module, and if everything went okay with the installation you will see something like this:

```
...
...
 ANDYA/File-Monitor-1.00.tar.gz
  ./Build install  -- OK
$
```

**Response to comments:**

`Preamble`: Your system has perl installed on it, however it is out of date.  But, your system needs perl to perform certain tasks, so you should NEVER delete or update the system perl.  In fact, you should leave the system perl alone, so that you don't screw it up and render your OS inoperable.  `perlbrew` to the rescue.

In your Applications folder, look for a Utilities folder, and inside the Utilities folder find `Terminal.app`.  Click on Terminal.app to launch a terminal window.

***Here are the steps for installing and using perlbrew:***

1) Install perlbrew:

```
~$ \curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

2) Install a perl with perlbrew:

```
~$ perlbrew install perl-5.23.6
```

Prior to installing a perl, you can see what versions of perl are available by doing this:

```
~$ perlbrew available
perl-5.23.6
perl-5.22.1
perl-5.20.3
perl-5.18.4
perl-5.16.3
...
...
```

Pick whatever version of perl you want to install and specify it in the install command above.

3) Tell perlbrew which perl version to use.  Because you will only have one version of perl installed at this point, write:

```
~$ perlbrew switch perl-5.23.6
```

perlbrew allows you to install multiple versions of perl, so if you have multiple versions of perl installed, and you want to switch to another version, you can do:

```
~$ perlbrew list
 perl-5.23.6
*perl-5.20.2
 perl-5.16.3

~$ perlbrew use perl-5.16.3

~$ perlbrew list
 perl-5.23.6
 perl-5.20.2
 *perl-5.16.3
```

The asterisk lets you know which version of perl you are currently using.

4) Install modules in the current version of perl:

```
~$ cpan Path::Class   !!DO NOT EVER USE SUDO!!
```

5) To see a list of all the modules installed in the current perl:

```
~$ perlbrew list-modules
CPAN::Meta
Date::Parse
File::Monitor
HTTP::CookieJar
HTTP::Date
...
...
...
```

6) perlbrew has a lot of other commands, so if you need to do something else, try searching through the output of:

```
~$ perlbrew --help
```

Comment: You skipped installing `perl` first! (which requires network access when done through `perlbrew`), and the use of `cpan` you recommend also requires network access.

Comment: @7stud I got it installed somehow. Now the problem are with my modules. I have installed the modules that I need and its successful, however When I give _instmodsh_ I can't find the module or when I run a script it says can't locate the module! Any tips on that, I'd really appreciate! Thanks

Comment: I have installed perl 5.22.1 using perlbrew and the modules I have installed are XML:::Simple, Data::Dumper, XML::Parser

Comment: @GRD, *I have installed the modules that I need and its successful* -- That doesn't provide enough detail.  *When I give instmodsh I can't find the module*--All you need is: `$ perlbrew list-modules`

Comment: I don't have the laptop in which I installed the modules, I mean to say the modules like XML::Simple, Data::Dumper, XML::Parser were all installed and it returned,  that 1 distribution installed successfully, for all the modules, however when I give _instmodsh_, it doesn't seem to list the installed modules there!

Comment: @GRD,  *I mean to say the modules like XML::Simple, Data::Dumper, XML::Parser were all installed and it returned, that 1 distribution installed successfully, for all the modules* --  Yeah, but it's the lines preceding that message that are vitally important because they tell you the location of the install.  Read over the steps I posted at the bottom of my answer.  If you still can't get to things to work, then install the module Modern::Perl and copy and paste every bit of text in your terminal window at the bottom of your question.